# EF Core create code-first stored procedures and modular structure

Tags: entity-framework-core, abp

I am developing a module (using abp framework) that needs to have some stored procedures in the database.

As a simple application I can create an empty migration and place my stored procedures scripts there.

As a modular application I need to place the SQL script somewhere that the final application can add it to database through migrations.

How can I force the final application to create stored procedures in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You have to **write custom code** and call it with other files in a pipeline and it will always being created/recreated whenever the backend app started